# How to use prefetch_related on two M2M values?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I want to `prefetch_related` to two level of M2M values,

Here is my models.py

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    b = models.ManyToManyField('B')

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    c = models.ManyToManyField('C')

class C(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    d = models.ManyToManyField('D')
```

And my ORM is

```
a_obj = A.objects.all().prefetch_related('a__b__c')
```

And I am trying to access the values like below,

**Method A:**

```
for each_obj in a_obj:
    print(each_obj.a__b__c)
```

**Method B:**

```
for each_obj in a_obj:
    print(each_obj.a.all())
```

**Method A** throws an error saying `No such value a__b__b for A found`
**Method B** doesn't throw any error, but the number of queries increases to the length of a_obj.

Is there a way to access `a__b__c` in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You load both the related `B` and `C` models with [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
a_objs = A.objects.prefetch_related('b__c')
```

But here `.prefetch_related(…)` does not change how the items *look*, it simply loads items. You thus can access these with:

```
for a in a_objs:
    for b in a.b.all():
        for c in b.c.all():
            print(f'{a} {b} {c}')
```

You this still access the items in the same way, but here Django will already load the objects in advance to prevent extra queries.